# Is it ethical to merge work and private SE accounts?

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

I am leaving a job and I would like to have access to the questions I asked on SE forums to be accessible to me. However, the account I used while working is bound to a work email address. I am thinking of merging my private account with my work account. Is this okay?

P.S. I am new on meta SE so I might have missed some tags or the topic is entirely misplaced. In this case, please tell me.

Comment: Can't see any issue here, as long as both are your own accounts.

Comment: Well, the gmail account I used for work is an account they issued me when I joint the firm. The domain is theirs.

Comment: Then it is a question to ask your employer. Whether they consider this account is their property or not. I don't think SE has anything to say about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE accounts are per person, not per company and as far as any of us care, its ethical. In theory, the only situation where this would matter is if you're representing the company in some official capacity, and that's sticky on its own. As long as the two accounts have been totally separate, its probably fine.

If the account is something your company asked you to create in an official capacity - in theory, they can't/are not supposed to use the account (since an account is a person) and ought to retire it.

I *personally* wouldn't recommend using a work email address (especially a google account) as the *only* login on an account through, depending on your workplace, since there's every possibility your account could get deleted before you could change the login method . (I wouldn't use it for anything either, but I've been through a few jobs so... unless it absolutely was official, I wouldn't bother).

So, as far as how we do things? Its probably entirely fine.

Comment: I was never representing the company. In fact, I made the account in order to resolve problems, some of which were private, other work-related. I was even told that none of them ever succeeded in getting an answer by posting on any forums, including SE.

Comment: Also, I wanted to merge the account to use my personal address.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>(disclaimer just in case it's not clear: I'm not a Stack Exchange employee nor am I officially speaking for the company)</sup>

Stack Exchange does not care. There is nothing wrong with doing it as far as Stack Exchange is concerned.

Now whether your company considers the account theirs as it was opened using their email and used on their time is something you need to ask your company.